# Exporting paths and configs in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, shell, export

I am trying to add some exports using the following method:

```
# SETUP CONFIGS
sudo bash -c "cat >> /etc/bash.bashrc" <<'EOF'
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/etc/test/aws.txt
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"
EOF
```

I have two questions:

1. For what ever reason, it simply isn't working, the config isnt being
   read by AWS as if it was never linked. Have I done this correctly?
2. Secondly, does this survive a reboot? As in, will I just have to do it once, and when I reboot the server it will still be there, or instead will I have to add these commands to my rc.local so they are reinstated on every reboot of the server.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear from your question exactly where and when you are running the scriptlet that you presented.

After you run the scriptlet do `cat /etc/bash.bashrc` to see if the two export lines are there.

The scriptlet adds two lines to `/etc/bash.bashrc` each time it runs. If you run it twice then you will have duplicate lines. The file `/etc/bash.bashrc` is a regular configuration file, not regenerated every boot, so any changes you make are persistent. So, you probably only want to run this script once on each platform you install it on.

In any event, `/etc/bash.bashrc` is probably not a good place to put global additions to `PATH`. You put those in `/etc/profile`. But before you do that, do `echo $PATH` to verify that `/usr/local/bin` isn't already there. In most distributions it is included in the PATH out-of-the-box.

Changes that you make to `/etc/bash.bashrc` will be effective for new `bash` processes such as terminal windows running `bash` that you start *after* you make the change. The change does not effect currently running windows.

The `PATH` environment variable that you set in `/etc/profile` of in a `.bashrc` file affects only bash shells. If you start a program from `crontab`, `at` or from an `/etc/rc.d` file, then you need to set the `PATH` specifically in those scripts, or use the `etc/environment` file to set environment variables for all processes. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150789/difference-between-bash-bashrc-and-etc-environment-file) link that explains the differences.

Answer (score 1):

System-wide environment variables can be placed in `/etc/environment`.

Once you added the lines you mentioned to `/etc/bash.bashrc`, every bash process should 'know' them. You can verify this, with:

```
echo $PATH
```

and

```
source /etc/bash.bashrc
echo $PATH
```

Also check out the Ubuntu Community Wiki on [Environment Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).